# Why is another thread, say B running when pthread_mutex is being locked and unlocked inside thread A?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

According to the man pages

> pthread_mutex_lock locks the given mutex. If the mutex is currently unlocked, it becomes locked  and  owned  by  the  calling  thread,  and
>          pthread_mutex_lock  returns  immediately.  If the mutex is already locked by another thread, pthread_mutex_lock suspends the calling thread
>          until the mutex is unlocked.

What I understood is when `line 3` executes the `main thread` has ownership of the `mtx`. It then performs its critcal region actions and then reaches `line 4` and unlocks `mtx`. My question is -

1. Can the other thread concurrently run when `mtx` is locked?
2. What is the use of `line 2` since `newThread` can only unlock `mtx` when `line 4` has been executed, and thus makes `line 2` redundant?
3. What would happen if `line 1` is uncommented?

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<pthread.h>
   #include<semaphore.h>
   #include<unistd.h>


   sem_t bin_sem;
   pthread_mutex_t mtx;
   char message[100];


   void * thread_function(void * arg)
   {   
       int x;
       char message2[10];
       while(1)
       {   

   //      pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); //line 1
           printf("thread2 : waiting..\n\n");
           sem_wait(&bin_sem);     
           printf("hi i am the new thread waiting inside critical..\n");
           scanf("%s",message);
           printf("You entered in newthread:%s\n\n",message);
           sem_post(&bin_sem);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); //line 2

       }

   }

   int main(void)
   {
       pthread_t athread;
       pthread_attr_t ta;
       char message2[10];
       int x;

       sem_init(&bin_sem,0,1);

       pthread_mutex_init(&mtx,NULL);

       pthread_attr_init(&ta);
       pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&ta,SCHED_RR);                                                                                                                                                                                                       

       pthread_create(&athread,&ta,thread_function,NULL);
       while(1)
       {   
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx); //line 3
           printf("main waiting..\n\n");
           sem_wait(&bin_sem); 
           printf("hi i am the main thread waiting inside critical..\n");
           scanf("%s",message);
           printf("You entered in main:%s\n\n",message);
           sem_post(&bin_sem);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); //line 4
       }
       sleep(5);       
   }
   ```

Comment: You should check the thread functions return values for errors.

Comment: @rustyx yes, i intentionally did that. If I uncomment it, only the `main thread` runs, and the `thread_function` never gets to execute. This is according to the output I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex *is* a mechanism for implementing critical sections.

Any code between `pthread_mutex_lock(x)` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(x)` calls will execute in only one thread at any given time. That's all.

So ...

> *1. Can the other thread concurrently run when mtx is locked?*

If it didn't lock the mtx, then of course.

> *2. What is the use of line 2 since newThread can only unlock mtx when line 4 has been executed, and thus makes line 2 redundant?*

The mutex becomes useless, and you also get [UB](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock) since you're unlocking it in the thread that didn't lock it:

> If the mutex type is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`...
>   Attempting to unlock the mutex if it was not locked by the calling thread results in undefined behavior.

(By default you get mutex type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`)

> *3. What would happen if line 1 is uncommented?*

You get [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685112/pthreads-thread-starvation-caused-by-quick-re-locking) [starvation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449732/fair-critical-section-linux), since the mutex is locked almost all the time and is immediately re-locked after unlocking (POSIX doesn't guarantee mutex fairness).

A POSIX [semaphore](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_post.html) does provide fairness in some cases (when you use `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR` schedulers), but is [heavier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex).

I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve (the application looks contrived). In a real application there's probably some logical ordering to the actions that either thread needs to take. So if the semaphore works for you, I'd keep it at that and remove the mutex.

Comment: Even if I don't  use any `pthread_mutex` statements, the critical region executes within only one thread at a given time, because of the `semaphore`. Does this mean encapsulating a `semaphore` within a `pthread_mutex` is redundant?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant.